# Laravel | Delete function - how to delete photo from calendar's event

Tags: laravel

How can I remove photo from calendar's event in edit calendar's event view? In list of events I did delete method and it works. Now when I try to do the same in edit.blade.php it gives error:

```
Call to a member function photos() on null
```

I have two tables in relationship one calendar to many photos, file upload works, but I stucked on edit part.

Look at my controller function:

```
public function deletePhoto(CalendarRepository $calRepo, $id)
    {
        $calendars = $calRepo->find($id);
        $calendars->photos($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->action('CalendarController@edit');
    }
```

and here is fragment of edit.blade.php:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="photo">Photo:</label>
  <div class="row">
      @foreach(($calendar->photos) as $photo)
           <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="admin-thumbnail">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="/storage/{{ $photo->filename }}" style="width:100px; height:auto;"/>
                </div>
                <a href="{{ URL::to('calendar/deletePhoto/' . $photo->id ) }}" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>Remove</a>
          </div>
      @endforeach
      </div>
</div>
```

I need to remove photo from Photo table and redirect to edit.blade.php (about the specific event id of the calendar)

Thanks for any help.

---

EDIT:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form action="{{ action ('CalendarController@editStore')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token() }}"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $calendar->id }}"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token() }}"/>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="photo">Photo:</label>
                   <div class="row">
                        @foreach(($calendar->photos) as $photo)
                             <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <div class="admin-thumbnail">
                                       <img class="img-responsive" src="/storage/{{ $photo->filename }}"/>
                                  </div>
                                  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('photo.delete', ['calendar' => $calendar, 'photo' => $photo]) }}">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method("DELETE")
                                        <a onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>Remove</a>
                                  </form>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                   </div>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="header">Header</label> 
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="header" value="{{ $calendar->header }}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="description">Description</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{ $calendar->description }}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="{{ $calendar->date }}"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
      </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The error you're seeing suggests that `$calRepo->find($id);` isn't finding a `Calendar` and is returning `null`. When you're then doing `$calendar->photos(...)` you're calling a method on `null` which doesn't make sense. Does the ID in this case definitely refer to an actual calendar in your database?

Comment: Also, in your template it looks like you're passing the ID of the photo but in your controller you're expecting `$id` to be the ID of the calendar which could explain what's going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same `$id` to find the photo and the calendar instance. 
GET request is not recommended for deleting a resource, so a better approach would be in your routes you can have something like this:

```
Route::delete('photo/{photo}', 'PhotosController@delete')->name('photo.delete');
```

Then in your view, you should surround the button with a Form, for example:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('photo.delete', $photo) }}">
@csrf
@method("DELETE")
<a onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>Remove</a>
</form>
```

Then your `confirm` function in JS should submit the form if the user accepts to delete the photo. And also remember to return false as default in the confirm function so it does not submits the form by default.

Your controller will then be:

```
public function delete(Photo $photo)
{   
    $photo->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

--- EDIT

```
Route::delete('calendar/{calendar}/photo/{photo}', 'CalendarController@deletePhoto')->name('photo.delete');
```

and the action in the form can be:

```
{{ route('photo.delete', ['calendar' => $calendar, 'photo' => $photo]) }}
```

The method in the controller:

```
public function deletePhoto(Calendar $calendar, Photo $photo)
{   
    $calendar->photos()->where('id', $photo->id)->delete();
    return redirect()->action('CalendarController@edit');
}
```

Comment: But I have photo's list in edit calendar's event view. I have method delete inside CalendarController. I am trying your answer but it doesn't work :/ 


I'm trying to create a calendar event edit. I wanted to delete and add photos from the event editing level.
Therefore, deleting from the calendar controller level.

Comment: @Giacomo My first approach is the restful approach, and it should work if you have the resources created as they should be. You can check out my edited answer if it does help for your scenario.

Comment: I'm not saying it does not work. Just after clicking the link and confirming the deletion, nothing happens.

Comment: @Giacomo That's why I said that you should submit the form. I don't see the content on your `confirm` function in JS. You can share it with me and I can help.

Comment: Oki, one moment

Comment: @Giacomo you have shared the view, but I need to see the body of this:

`return confirm('Are you sure?')` so from the confirm action. On your positive callback, which means whenever the user presses Okay, what do you call? You should call `this.form.submit()` or something similar that will proceed with the delete form submission.

Comment: Hmm, I added full of form content, but I don't have JS function. In list of calendar's events I deleted them just using: <a href="{{ URL::to('calendar/delete/' . $calendar->id ) }}"
                           onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>Remove</a></td>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184231/discussion-between-nakov-and-giacomo).